# Using Bluetooth ANE for Android

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bluetooth

I'm relatively new to flash, air and AS3 so I'm sorry if this comes of as a beginners question. I have made an application in AIR to run on windows and communicate with my atmega8 chip through serial communication via serproxy.

Now I want to port that application to android to perform the same basic functions but communicate to the atmega8 via bluetooth. So I created a new Air for android file in Flash CS6 copied my code from my previous application excluding the communication through sockets part and created an apk which ran on an android phone:). It did everything except the communication as expected.

Now I have been trying to implement the as3breeze.com/bluetooth-ane and use it to communicate but I'm not too sure how to go about the whole thing. I have imported the ane through actionscript settings and have implemented the classes but when I try to test I get this error.

The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Extension namespace is invalid for C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages\AndroidBluetooth.ane

So after some searching I found posts talking about as3 sdk and flash builder. Do I really need all these things or can I make my bluetooth app work some how with just flash cs6? Also what exactly does my error mean and how can I solve it. Thanks in advance for any help. I have been searching so a solution to this for days and I either get an explanation that does not work or I lack the knowledge to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that can't be accessed makes me believe you haven't extracted the ANE (basically you're trying to access a temporary directory). Try extracting the ANE file to somewhere, like My Documents or wherever your flash project is, and include (in the actionscript settings) that path instead.
 Hope it helps.